# Most efficient way to find the equidistant point (or most equidistant) from a path to Points A and B

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find the most efficient way to, given a path formed by points (where every consecutive point is united by a line) in a 2D reference system, find which of these points is the one most equidistant to two arbitrary given points.

I could simply go through all the points and find which one is the closest but i do not think this is the most efficient.

My initial approach was to find the closest point from the set of points to each point individually, and then going to the point in between those two points that I found and try with the middle one, and do this recursively until the solution converges or diverge.

I am not sure if this would be the best approach though. I would appreciate some input.Thank you

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "the most equidistant"?

Comment: The point where the difference of distance from A to the point of the set of points and the distance from B to that same point of the set of points is minimum

Comment: So a point with distances $d_A=10$ and $d_B=8$ and another point with $d_A=5$ and $d_B=3$ would be equally equidistant? Then it is not a way forward to consider only points on the path closest to $A$ and/or $B$. For an arbitrary path I don't see any way to avoid considering all points on the path.